# How can I fetch all the MAC addresses of devices on a network in C#/pcap?

Tags: c#, network-programming, pcap

I got a project to build a bridge in a network not connected to the internet.
In order to know what packets to transfer or not I need to have the mac addresses of the devices on either side.
How can I fetch these devices with a broadcast or something in c#?
Thanks.

Comment: Ping every IP address in the subnet.  The MAC will be returned in the ARP response.  You can then get the info either in the ping response or from the aRP table.

Comment: @djweng but how can I know the IP addresses in a just hooked up network?

Comment: Your interface should have an IP address and a Mask.  The subnet is be the size of mask.  To get the mask in a cmd.exe window, type : IPCONFIG /ALL